# CarrierWave: Image not Showing on the Show Page Error: NoMethodError in Posts#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to show images in my app using Carrierwave gem with Ruby on Rails. I am using the multiple image upload option which is supported in Carrierwave. Everythings is working fine except when i go to the show page i get this error: **NoMethodError in Posts#show**

[image]

**Here's the code**

**my show.html.erb page**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= image_tag @post.image.url %>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @post.name %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@post , html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image %><br>
    <%= f.file_field :image , multiple: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**post_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:name, {image:[]})
    end
end
```

**The Model  post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :image, ImageUploader

end
```

Comment: Seems that `@post.image` returns an Array. Try `@post.image.first.id`

Comment: could you please try image_tag(@post.image_url) and let me know if works . 
Thanks

Comment: `<%= image_tag @post.image %>`

And fix `params.require(:post).permit(:name, {image:[]})` into `params.require(:post).permit(:name, :image)`

Comment: i did the first option but when i show the image i get this error http://pho.to/9nveX searched the site for this issue and couldn't find why the image is not showing http://goo.gl/8WSxxA

Answer (score 1):

In your post_params you have defined image param as an array

```
params.require(:post).permit(:name, {image:[]})
```

either you should retrieve images from this array using iteration as:

```
<% @post.image.each do |image| %>
    <%= image_tag image.url %>
<% end %>
```

which would display all images posted on this post
or if you just want to save a single image for the post then change

```
params.require(:post).permit(:name, {image:[]})
```

to

```
params.require(:post).permit(:name, :image)
```

and everything will work fine!

**Note:**

```
<%= image_tag @post.image[0].url %>
```

will also work for the code you have written as it will just fetch the url of first image in that image array

Comment: i did the first option but when i show the image i get this http://pho.to/9nveX i searched the site for this issue and couldn't find why the image is not showing http://goo.gl/8WSxxA

Comment: Try <%= image_tag image.url.to_s %> instead. Also log the resulting url of the image and try to open that image in new tab with that url.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either. Is it possible that the bug is from the Gem it self ??

Comment: did you try printing the url formed and check whether it was correct or not? Currently the gem is not having any such bug, seems like the error is in implementation